# React Native Failed to Build: NDK not installed, even after adding ndk.dir to local.properties

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, android-ndk

I try to run my react native project, but got `NDK not installed` error. I already add ndk.dir on local.properties but still the error occurs.
[image]

This is the error:[image]

Any idea what's wrong with my project. Thanks!